# How can I get POST data in swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have configured swagger-ui in my SpringBoot application.

Following is my code

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    openAppUrl("8080/swagger-ui.html");
}

public static void openAppUrl(String port) {
    String url = "http://localhost:" + port;
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {

        if (os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
            rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
        } else if (os.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
            try {
                rt.exec("open " + url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } else if (os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || os.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {

            String[] browsers = { "epiphany", "firefox", "mozilla", "konqueror", "netscape", "opera", "links",
                    "lynx" };
            StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++)
                cmd.append((i == 0 ? "" : " || ") + browsers[i] + " \"" + url + "\" ");

            rt.exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", cmd.toString() });

        } else {
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
    return;
}
}
```

My Controller

```
package com. server.spring.controller;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com. server.spring.domain.User;
    import com. server.spring.service.UserService;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(UsersController.ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH)
    public class UsersController {

        public static final String ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/rest/secure/v1/users";

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;


        @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public List<User> getUsers() {
            return userService.getAllUsers();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            return userService.saveUser(user);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Here it shows the Rest API URL, HTTP Method POST, Response JSON Object.  But I don't see the POST Data Obj which is expected in the API call. So without this the Front End developers cann't work on the corresponding API.

So i expect to show POST Data JSON object what this REST Api required from Front end application

Is this the correct way or Do i need to modify it to get the expected one?

Comment: you are returning same response json, which you are accepting as response body, above model (in your screenshot) is response, below one is request body

Comment: @HemantPatel: Thanks. So as per you comment. What i am getting is correct (request body POST data)?

Comment: Yes, in case you want something else, you need to change request / response structure in your controller

Comment: Got it Thanks Hemant

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of Swagger-ui, that looks like 2.x
The latest is a lot easier to understand, Check it out here:
http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/addPet
It sounds like you are giving this to other developers (the Front End developers), In that case I strongly suggest you to look for a way to upgrade, the new version has a much better user experience, also the 2.x UI version is no longer supported.

So to answer your question:

> How can I get POST data in swagger-ui?

The actual response you can get it with the [try-it-out] button of the swagger-ui.
And the POST Data Obj expected by the API is what you see on the example.

Answer (score 0):

I got model properties to correctly attach to the body by using examples (Techincally, API Model Properties) on the models. However, my experience with this didn't include Spring, I'm sure that the documentation is similar. You'd add `@ApiModelProperty` annotation to your `User` class.

```
public class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "User's first name.", example = "John")
  public String getFirstName(){}
  //...setters

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "User's last name.", example = "Smith")
  public String getLastName(){}
  //...setters

  // etc
}
```

This fills the swagger documentation POST/PUT/etc body with your `example` strings.